# How to convert a div layout to an HTML table based on CSS styles?

Tags: python, html, css

I'm working on a project where I need to convert a complex layout designed with `<div>` elements into an HTML table using `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, `<colspan>`, and `<rowspan>` tags. The layout is currently styled using CSS, and I want to retain the same structure and appearance when converting it into a table format.

**Input:**
I have a series of `<div>` elements that represent both headers and data cells in a tabular format. Each `<div>` has multiple class attributes that correspond to specific CSS styles defining their position and size. Here's a snippet of the current div-based layout:

```html
<div class="c x1b y41 wf h14">Project</div>
<div class="c x20 y43 w10 h6">2023</div>
<div class="c x21 y43 w11 h6">2022</div>
<div class="c x23 y43 w12 h6">2021</div>
<div class="c x1e y43 w13 h6">2020</div>

<div class="c x20 y41 w14 h9">Amount</div>
<div class="c x26 y41 w15 h9">Ratio</div>
<div class="c x21 y41 w16 h9">Amount</div>
<div class="c x28 y41 w17 h9">Ratio</div>
<div class="c x23 y41 w18 h9">Amount</div>
<div class="c x29 y41 w19 h9">Ratio</div>
<div class="c x1e y41 w1a h9">Amount</div>
<div class="c x2a y41 w1b h9">Ratio</div>

<div class="c x1b y44 wf h6">Income</div>
<div class="c x20 y44 w14 h6">9.6</div>
<div class="c x26 y44 w15 h6">100.00</div>
<div class="c x21 y44 w16 h6">377.78</div>
<div class="c x28 y44 w17 h6">100.00</div>
<div class="c x23 y44 w18 h6">293.47</div>
<div class="c x29 y44 w19 h6">100.00</div>
<div class="c x1e y44 w1a h6">210.66</div>
<div class="c x2a y44 w1b h6">100.00</div>
```

**CSS Styles:**
The layout is controlled by these CSS styles, which dictate the dimensions and positions of the divs:

```css
.h14 {height: 41.215200px;}
.h6 {height: 20.280000px;}
.h9 {height: 20.311200px;}
.w10 {width: 116.095200px;}
.w11 {width: 116.251200px;}
.w12 {width: 116.376000px;}
.w13 {width: 122.959200px;}
.w14 {width: 55.099200px;}
.w15 {width: 60.216000px;}
.w16 {width: 58.188000px;}
.w17 {width: 57.283200px;}
.w18 {width: 61.152000px;}
.w19 {width: 54.600000px;}
.w1a {width: 61.963200px;}
.w1b {width: 60.372000px;}
.wf {width: 73.008000px;}
.x1b {left: 112.450000px;}
.x1e {left: 537.830800px;}
.x20 {left: 186.914000px;}
.x21 {left: 303.641000px;}
.x23 {left: 420.511000px;}
.x26 {left: 242.801000px;}
.x28 {left: 362.609000px;}
.x29 {left: 482.287000px;}
.x2a {left: 600.262000px;}
.y41 {bottom: 490.373000px;}
.y43 {bottom: 511.303000px;}
.y44 {bottom: 469.313000px;}
```

**Expected Result:**
I want to convert this layout into an HTML table. The expected table structure should resemble the following:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Project</td>
    <td colspan="2">2023</td>
    <td colspan="2">2022</td>
    <td colspan="2">2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">2020</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>Ratio</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>Ratio</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>Ratio</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>Ratio</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Income</td>
      <td>9.6</div></td>
      <td>100.00</td>
      <td>377.78</td>
      <td>100.00</td>
      <td>293.47</td>
      <td>100.00</td>
      <td>210.66</td>
      <td>100.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Attempts:**
I have tried several methods to parse the divs and apply their styles to create a table, but none have worked effectively. I've experimented with JavaScript to dynamically read the CSS properties and apply them as attributes to table cells, but I'm encountering issues with maintaining the layout's integrity, especially when it comes to spanning rows and columns.

**Question:**
Can anyone provide guidance or a solution on how to programmatically convert this div-based layout into an HTML table, considering the CSS styles? Any help with parsing the CSS to define the appropriate `<colspan>` and `<rowspan>` values in the table would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Frankly, it would be quicker to just rewrite the HTML and CSS than attempt to parse your current code to create something in an actual `table`. Your classes have nothing to do with structure *per se* but rather appearance and location.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want it to look like a table and not the semantics. You can try doing it with grid and fixed number of columns using something like `grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr)`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).